# Are there any instruments to watch screen layout in React Native without running app?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I familiarized with Android development and started to read some information about React Native. And one of the problem which I faced with is that I can't see the screen layout.

In Android Studio, for example, I could see the design of my XML layout without running app. Maybe there are such instruments in React Native, but I didn't see them in WebStorm nor VSCode. Maybe I am wrong and they exist, so, can you help me to find them in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Some modules format the xml document in `vscode`,

but others have previewable tools.

[XML TOOLS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml)

[image: xml tools]

**Extension Settings**

- `xmlTools.enableXmlTreeView`: Enables the XML Tree View for XML
  documents.
- `xmlTools.enableXmlTreeViewMetadata`: Enables attribute and child
  element counts in the XML Document view.
- `xmlTools.enableXmlTreeViewCursorSync`: Enables auto-reveal of
  elements in the XML Document view when a start tag is clicked in the
  editor.
- `xmlTools.enforcePrettySelfClosingTagOnFormat`: Ensures a space is
  added before the forward slash at the end of a self-closing tag.

...

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem where there is no layout view in VSCode like in Android Studio. My suggestion is to mock out your View containers with coloured boxes. This is an example of designing a screen's header, so I'm making sure the spacing and sizing is all good:

[image]